# fluid template and TYPO3: Form inside a form - submit doesn't work anymore

Tags: typo3, fluid

If i insert a form inside a form, the submit button in the "outer" form doesn't work anymore.

Short code example:

```
<f:form action="update" name="examples" object="{examples}" >
  <f:for each="{examples}" as="example"

    <f:form.textfield property="name" value="" />
    <f:form.checkbox property="checked" value="1" checked="0" /><br />
    <f:form action="delete" name="example" object="{example}" >
        <f:form.submit value="delete" />
    </f:form>
<f:form.submit value="update" />
</f:form>
```

So basically (this is an extremely simplified version of my real life project) i want to be able to change the values of the textfield and checkbox which are then passed to the updateAction. The for each loop just generates multiple entries and therefore multiple forms just containing the delete button for that specific object so to speak. I can address these objects by __identity and they can be deleted by the button next to them, that's not the problem.

But the submit button for update doesn't work anymore if i put other forms with their respective submit buttons into this form.

Is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forms inside forms do not work (and is not proper HTML either).

Longer version that answers the question you didn't ask: to achieve your goal here, use `f:link.action` to create a link to the `delete` controller action with your `{example}` object as parameter. Then style that link to look like a button if you wish.

Comment: As i also work in combination with javascript i think your f:link.action solution works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Completely unrelated from TYPO3 or Fluid you should know that nesting forms is not allowed.

However, at least the editing part of your code can be made valid with a single form:

```
<f:form action="update" name="examples" object="{examples}" >

  <f:for each="{examples}" as="example" iteration="i">
    <f:form.textfield property="{i}.name"/>
    <f:form.checkbox property="{i}.checked" value="1"/>
  </f:for>

  <f:form.submit value="update"/>
</f:form>
```

With this set up it is not possible to also have a delete action in place since you'd need a submit button which does two things:

1. Request the `delete` action:

   `<f:form.button type="submit" name="action" value="delete">Delete</f:form.button>`
2. Point at the entity to address:

   `<f:form.button type="submit" name="example" value="{example}">Do something with {example.title}</f:form.button>`

You should add a separate view for editing single `example` objects instead. The current view then becomes a list with links to that edit view. In that view your form `object` becomes a single `example` which allows you to add two submit buttons for each `action`.